# To get number of sports player

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I have many photos with high resolution. I am going to get number of marathon player from the photo.
example images: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rfOnnKDUmbR3A8xAhpwHdykhNFfMR1QG

To solve this problem, I was going to do following steps.

1. Detect person in the image
2. Detect number region in the person area
3. Get number using tesseract or tensorflow-ocr

I detected person successfully using yolo3. But in my image, it was very hard to get number region using findContours. The number of points is not 4. So I filtered rectangles with area of it and get some rectangles. I am not sure this is correct method.
But I ran into problem in next step.
I tried to get number from those areas, but it could not get correct numbers. I tried to do preprocessing, but the result was not improved.

```
        imgOriginalScene = cv2.bilateralFilter(imgOriginalScene, 11, 17, 17)
        cv2.imshow("Bilateral", imgOriginalScene)

        kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
        imgOriginalScene = cv2.erode(imgOriginalScene,kernel,iterations = 2)
        cv2.imshow("Erode", imgOriginalScene)

        kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
        imgOriginalScene = cv2.dilate(imgOriginalScene,kernel,iterations = 2)
        cv2.imshow("Dilate", imgOriginalScene)

        imgOriginalScene = cv2.Canny(imgOriginalScene, 30, 200)
        cv2.imshow("Canny", imgOriginalScene)

        imgCanny = imgOriginalScene

        contours = cv2.findContours(imgOriginalScene.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

        imgContours = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

        rects = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in contours]
        rects = sorted(rects,key=lambda  x:x[1],reverse=True)

        imgRect = imgCrop
        imgRectDisp = imgCrop

        imgRect = cv2.cvtColor(imgRect, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret_thresh, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgRect, kmeans(input_img=imgRect, k=8, i_val=5)[0], 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imshow("or", thresh)

        i = -1
        j = 1
        y_old = 5000
        x_old = 5000
        for rect in rects:
            x,y,w,h = rect
            area = w * h

            if w > h and w < h * 4 :
                i += 1
                y_old = y

                x,y,w,h = rect

                cv2.rectangle(imgContours, (x , y ), (x + w , y + h ), color, 1)
                cv2.rectangle(imgRectDisp, (x , y ), (x + w , y + h ), color, 3)

                bbcrop = thresh[y : y + h, x : x + w]
                config = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 3')
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(bbcrop, config=config)
                print("OCR " + text)

                j += 1

        cv2.imshow("contours", imgContours)
        cv2.imshow("rectangle", imgRectDisp)
```

In my code, tesseract could not detect the number. I wonder if my preprocessing is not appropriate.

Also I want to know how to improve tesseract accuracy. Should I train own model for OCR? Could someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for a robust approach you can apply to any set of image as long as it contains marathon runners, or do you want to process only the images you uploaded?

Comment: I have many images of marathon players. of course, I am looking for a robust approach. I also trained font for pytesseract, but I could not get any result :(
Is there any way to improve tesseract accuracy or I have to train my own model? If I have to train model, which approach is best for OCR in my images?